# How to use go test flag to execute test and bench function correctly?

Tags: go, testing, go-testing

I learn from the go flags from [Testing flags](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-Testing_flags)

And I write some test files in my project.

This is my `service` folder:

- service

  - family_limit_settings.go
  - family_limit_settings_test.go
  - xxxxxx.go (others go source files)
  - xxxxxx_test.go (others go test source files)

and my `family_limit_settings_test.go` content is as follows:

```golang
func TestSaveSettings(t *testing.T) {
    // todo
}

func TestListByFamilyId(t *testing.T) {
    // todo
}

func TestFamilyLimitVerify(t *testing.T) {
    // todo
}

func BenchmarkFamilyListByFamilyId(b *testing.B) {
    // todo
}

func BenchmarkFamilySaveSettings(b *testing.B) {
    // todo
}

func BenchmarkFamilyLimitVerify(b *testing.B) {
    // todo
}
```

### my first question

I `cd` this service file and run command follow:

```sh
 go test -v -bench=.
```

But I find it run other test function those are not benchmark function.(I know it because something wrong occurs in other common test function)

### my second question

```sh
go test -v -bench=. -run=BenchmarkFamilyListByFamilyId
```

I want to execute the benchmark function with the name `BenchmarkFamilyListByFamilyId` but I found it execute all the benchmark functions.

Comment: 1. `family_limit_settings-test.go` probably should be `family_limit_settings_test.go`: Its a _underscore_ that separates "test". 2. If you do not want to run test you have to make sure none get run e.g. via `-run x`.

Comment: 1. I just write wrong here, I edit it.

Comment: 2. -run regexp
    Run only those tests and examples matching the regular expression.
    For tests, the regular expression is split by unbracketed slash (/)
    characters into a sequence of regular expressions, and each part
    of a test's identifier must match the corresponding element in
    the sequence, if any. Note that possible parents of matches are
    run too, so that -run=X/Y matches and runs and reports the result
    of all tests matching X, even those without sub-tests matching Y,
    because it must run them to look for those sub-tests.

Answer (score 2):

The -run argument matches tests and examples only, -bench matches benchmarks. And `.` is a regular expression that matches every name, so `-bench=.` executes all benchmarks.

To execute only the BenchmarkFamilyListByFamilyId benchmark and none of the tests, run something like

```
go test -v -bench=ByFamilyId -run=XXX
```

Comment: -bench regexp
    Run only those benchmarks matching a regular expression.
-run regexp
    Run only those tests and examples matching the regular expression.
I know now but that is a really strange design. 
both bench and run flag execute that only match the regular expression, which is clear now.
But don't specify bench flag would execute nothing benchmark, don't specify run flag however run any test and example.

Comment: Making the most common use-case -- testing a package -- require no options isn't strange to me at all.